# Securely Move files on an HTML page

Tags: javascript, security, copy

To preface what my end goal is:  On an HTML page I've already created, I need to add a section where users can input multiple file sources and destinations, click go and it copies them- showing what the status is.  I'm not asking for all of that to be done here, my goal right now is just:
My problem that I can't seem to get around is finding a way of doing this without uploading it to the server first- Just want it A to B as if the user is copying it themselves (mostly for security reasons).  The reason I'm trying to do it this way is so the eu can go about doing other things while it runs in the background.  Let me know if I need to answer any questions.

Comment: Are you asking a way for javascript to use the browser to move files from one place on a user hard drive to another? That's not going to happen. It that were allowed, it would be a security nightmare.

Comment: If you're talking about moving files on the client's computer, Javascript is pretty limited on what it's allowed to do for security reasons. You've looked over the File API?

Comment: Hmm, ok.  I was assuming that would be the 'more' secure way.  I was just now looking into java, and wondering if that would be a better way of doing it.
What transfer method is really the best way to go with this?  It's going to have to go PC to server (their personal drive), then I would have another HTML page for them to do the opposite on a different PC, going server to PC.